# How to stop a cmd file from showing Network error messages

Tags: cmd

Error Message I want to remove:

[image]

I get this error when I run a code that runs a shortcut that's shared over network.

How can I stop cmd script from showing Network Errors like these, even if I know there is an error?

Comment: You *might* be able to do it [like this](https://superuser.com/a/1319468), but you should probably include a way to change the registry entry back to what it was, once your script ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
echo.
echo 1. Add
echo 2. Remove
echo.
set /p var= Type option number here - 
if %var%==1 (goto :add)
if %var%==2 (goto :remove)
if else (goto :EOF)

:add
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\ /v RestoreConnection /d 0
echo.
echo SUCESSFULLY ADDED!
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul &exit

:remove
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\ /v RestoreConnection
echo.
echo SUCESSFULLY REMOVED!
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul &exit
```

This .bat script could come handy btw. Atleast it's easier than changing the registry manually. You can add and delete the value any time you want, so its convenient. Save this as a (.bat) file and use it...

Thanks @FiddlingAway for giving reference for the script : )